# How to send string stream over wifi on android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, flutter, outputstream

I am connecting an Esp32 with my android phone over wifi, that is the esp is working as an Access Point server. Trying to send a String to be read by the esp.
Here is the link for the esp code on arduino IDE:

[Wifi_AP_server](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pr5zmLAwbE7ND2LSH4CI3mXaL6HsV5nv/view?usp=sharing)

There are a lot of help regarding java sockets in here but none of streams works with me and I really can not wrap my head around them in this simple case to come up with my implementation !! 
I write this java code in MainActivity.java inside an AsyncTask and it is a part of the MethodChannel to be called by flutter.

```
Socket socket = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
socket = new Socket("192.168.4.1", 80);
outputStream = new DataOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeUTF("Hello\n");
socket.close();
```

Please note that this is glitchy because sometimes it successfully send two characters or one , most of the times it just connects and disconnects with the esp without sending any character. I tried all I can try different streams, reading a message buffer from esp to phone and writing back to that buffer as if it is an echo server, which worked well but that is not a wanted scenario !!

I decided to ask this question here after I wrote this python snippet code that made me sure that the Wifi_AP_server.ino esp code is working properly.

```
import socket
HOST = '192.168.4.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 80        # The port used by the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world\n')
    data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
```

You can try this with the link and you will find it working properly. 
Hence, please help me , how shall I do this using java on android ?

Comment: `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` uses a proprietary format that is well-documented in the Javadocs. It includes binary length bytes and is not going to be compatible with a server that expects the kind of input the python code is sending. Perhaps you meant to do `outputStream.write("Hello world\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: I tried `getBytes("UTF-8")` also, this time I wrote exactly what you told  and it sends everytime consistently the first letter "H" only without the rest of the sentence. Even in C it was better to deal with sockets than Java in my perspective. Last thing I also tried reading from an input stream wrapping the string to be sent into a buffer then sending that buffer through the output stream inside a while loop and also not successful !!!

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of more help. You did get rid of `writeUTF()`, correct?

Comment: Yes of course I ditched `writeUTF()`